# Posting a copied picture directly to Amazon Chime from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-chime

Afternoon all, kind of a specific request!
I currently have a project that posts directly to Amazon Chime using the following code:

```
Sub MessageChime(WebHook As String, MessageContent As String)
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Dim body As String
    body = "{""Content"":""" + MessageContent + """}"
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oHttp.Open "POST", WebHook, False
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    oHttp.send body
End Sub
```

It works a treat for sure. But i'm wondering, using the HTTP POST if it's possible to send a picture instead?

My thought process would be to post a portion of a sheet, directly as a picture to chime, but currently the code I'm using is only good for text! Does anyone have any ideas using any other means that this could be possible?

I know it's quite specific, but maybe somebody can give me some pointers? :) Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about which API you're using to post text?

Comment: I'm not fully sure what the API is I will be honest! I feel like i want to say SDK? If that's what the API is referring too

Comment: Yes - is there any documentation which covers posting pictures?  Not even sure what Amazon Chime is...

Comment: Not that i can see, just having a quick scan :)

Comment: Amazon Chime is a chat app that is used for Amazon, mostly internally :)

Comment: Try searching for the URL you're using to post text.

Comment: The URL i'm posting to is a webhook that I added to one of the chat rooms. But i just can't seem to get it to accept a picture :)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/ug/webhooks.html says "Webhooks currently don't support attachments"

Comment: Certainly a spanner in the works :) nevermind then :P thanks for looking